# How can I create multiple UISwitches from an array positioned one after another?

Tags: xcode, swift4, uiswitch

I have a popup view, that I would like to populate with ~15 UISwitches. Now it would be stupid to do all of that manually, so in Android I have set up a for loop to create said UISwitches from an array and you are able to toggle each one on and off and so on, each having their own value. I have created one switch, but when trying to create multiple from an array, none show up and I have no idea how I would be able to position them one after another.

```
let mySwitch = UISwitch()
mySwitch.isOn = false
mySwitch.center = self.view.center
mySwitch.thumbTintColor = UIColor(red: 23.0/255, green: 145.0/255, blue: 255.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
mySwitch.tintColor = UIColor(red: 23.0/255, green: 145.0/255, blue: 255.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
mySwitch.onTintColor = UIColor.black
mySwitch.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

self.view.addSubview(mySwitch)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var scrol = UIScrollView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
scrol.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 200)
            var yPos = 0.0
            for i in 0...10 {
                let mySwitch = UISwitch()
                mySwitch.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: yPos + 10, width: 50, height: 25)
                mySwitch.isOn = false
               // mySwitch.center = self.view.center
                mySwitch.tag = i
                mySwitch.thumbTintColor = UIColor(red: 23.0/255, green: 145.0/255, blue: 255.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
                mySwitch.tintColor = UIColor(red: 23.0/255, green: 145.0/255, blue: 255.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
                mySwitch.onTintColor = UIColor.black
                mySwitch.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                yPos = Double(mySwitch.frame.origin.y + mySwitch.frame.size.height)
                mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onSwitchChange(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                scrol.addSubview(mySwitch)
            }
            scrol.backgroundColor = .yellow
            scrol.isScrollEnabled = true
            self.view.addSubview(scrol)
    }
func onSwitchChange(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    print(" switch tapped \(sender.tag)")

}
```

Check out this, i have added a scrollView inside a UIView and have added multiple UISwitch as you have given in code with Frame set for UISwitch.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking at [`UIStackView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview).

This allows you to easily add multiple UI elements to the screen at consistent positions without any hassle.

First you'd want to create a stack view:

```
let stackView = UIStackView()
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
stackView.axis = .vertical
stackView.spacing = 10
```

add it and constrain it:

```
view.addSubview(stackView)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
    // etc, etc
])
```

Then you'd simply add a series of switches to the stack view:

```
for i in 0..<10 {
    let switch = UISwitch()
    // Configure switch
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(switch)
}
```